# CouchBase Get All Keys and Values in database with .NET Client

Tags: .net, client, key, couchbase

I just installed CouchBase 1.8 and am using .NET client to interact with it. I would like to know if there is any way to get all the keys stored in a bucket (and values). Even if its not a .NET solution, its fine as long as it works.

Thanks
V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the Couchbase Server 2.0 Beta - http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/beta.  With that version, you'll be able to use a view to get all docs in a bucket.

```
function (doc, meta)
{
   emit(meta.id, null);
}
```

Then using the .NET 1.2 Beta client, you'll be able to iterate over all docs (or use the web console to view the results of the view).

Edited to include .NET sample:

Once you've created the view using the JavaScript Map function above, you would use the .NET Client as follows (assuming you created a design document named "utils" and a view named "all_keys":

```
var view = client.GetView("utils", "all_keys");
foreach(var row in view)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current ID: " + row.ItemId);
}
```

or:

```
var keys = view.Select(row => row.ItemId); //get an IEnumerable<string> of IDs
foreach(var key in keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current ID: " + key);
}
```

More on the .NET Client and views at http://blog.couchbase.com/strongly-typed-views-net-client-library.

-- jz

Comment: Ok can you show the code more elaborately? Or any links which explain that. Currently it looks like javascript code ! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is JavaScript code...  In Couchbase Server 2.0, you can create indexes on your documents.  Even if you're not using JSON as the format for storage, you could still create an index on the keys as above.  The docs for views are at:

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views.html

Comment: Thanks John. We will give it a shot and see how it goes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Happy to help.  Let me know if you need any more details.